# align div's to bottom with margin applied

Tags: html, css

how can we align all the list items to the bottom of the parent separated by a margin.

If I apply position: absolute; bottom: 0, all elements align to the bottom but margins are discarded.

```
 #bars0 {
width: 472px;
height: 258px;
position: relative;
 }
 #bars0 li {
border: solid red 1px;
width: 30px;
height: 50px;
margin-right: 95px;
position: absolute;
    bottom: 0   
}

  <div id="bars0">
   <ul><!-- update: added ul -->
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> 
  <li></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't make the bottom zero.

Comment: You can set `bottom: Xpx` where x is equal to the amount of margin you want.

Comment: then the won't align to the bottom of parent div

Comment: @EricLemos yes I did that, but I want spacing between list items, and because of position absolute, the margins are discarded.

Comment: Any reason why you can't surround the `<li>` with a `<ul>` tag and absolutely position the `<ul>`? That way you could control the margin of internal `<li>`?? 

Thusly: http://jsfiddle.net/RYBFF/

You'll need to adjust the margin on the last item to get it to fit in the container though.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper are you referring to the list items stacking on top of each other? your code doesn't paint a well enough picture for me

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper You should see this link: [stackoverflow.com/questions/4230983/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230983/can-you-have-lis-without-them-being-under-a-ul-or-ol). You're markup is invalid. Browser's are forgiving and therefore letting it work but proper markup would have `<li>` placed inside of one of the following: `<ul>`, `<ol>`,`<menu>`, or `<dir>`. For help with validation please see the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @sbeliv01 your solution is close, however, there's one glitch, i can't align all the bars absolutely bottom, can you edit the code on js fiddle and change margin-right to just 50 px, so I can see all divs bottom lined up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you can't surround the `<li>` with a `<ul>` tag and absolutely position the `<ul>`? That way you could control the margin of internal `<li>`??

The HTML:

```
<div id="bars0">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li> 
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#bars0 {
    width: 472px;
    height: 258px;
    position: relative;
}

#bars0 ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#bars0 li {
    border: solid red 1px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 95px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#bars0 li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Thusly: http://jsfiddle.net/RYBFF/1/

To address your recent request on the comments: Just remove the margin from the last item in the list using :last-child on the `<li>` as shown above.

Comment: another request, possible to change the fiddle so each bar has a variable height, I'm finding list items getting stuck to the top edge of enclosing ul tag, just want them positioned at the bottom like bar charts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#bars{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5px;    
}
#bars ul li {
    float: left;
    min-width:100px;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="bars">
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/YYCZc/2/

Comment: hi James, I see the Test and Test 2 vertically stacked, I want to see them in one row like cells in a table row.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper: Updated the example and Fiddle.