# put a `<custom-tag>` instead of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` to create a list

Tags: html, css

Before you mark this as duplicate: i've seen this [Can you have <li>s without them being under a <ul> or <ol>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230983/can-you-have-lis-without-them-being-under-a-ul-or-ol) but they solve the problem by using styles.

Here is my question: can I have `<li>` items inside a `<custom-tag>` instead of `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements?

so something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

would look like this:

```
<custom-tag>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>three</li>
</custom-tag>
```

**The context of the problem**

I want to create a new component for [simditor](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor): a component for roman numerals on an orderer list, but it recognizes the `ol` as his "built-in" `ol` button... it seems like it uses the tag names to detect whether the button is active on a piece of the editor, so I want to fix this by using a tag with another name, right now, this solution seems easier than rewriting the whole library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.

> ### [4.4.7 The `li` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)
>
> #### [Contexts in which this element can be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-contexts):
>
> - Inside [`ol`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) elements.
> - Inside [`ul`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) elements.

If you want to use custom elements for the lists, you could also use them for the items:

```
<unordered-list>
  <list-item>one</list-item>
  <list-item>two</list-item>
  <list-item>d</list-item>
  <list-item>three</list-item>
</unordered-list>
```

Comment: the `<li>` tags could be replaced too, with the `display: list-item` style... even with that what i want to do would be impossible? :(

Comment: @Bengalaa Well you can use it but it won't be valid.

Answer (score 2):

While `li` elements are not allowed to exist outside of `ul` and `ol` elements, it's worth nothing that while hacky, Chrome does seem to support this as a possibility (though I wouldn't recommend it).

```css
roman {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<roman>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</roman>
```

Comment: thanks! but i want the solution to be compatible with other browsers too :( anyway... i guess it is a good solution if you are considering to launch an app for google chrome users :)

Comment: I didn't say it was only compatible in Chrome, but that's all I tested it in. Have you tried running the code snippet in other browsers to see?

Comment: sorry, i think i misunderstood you... it works on chromium, but it doesn't work on firefox... it displays all elements with `0. item` lol... well, it works on chrome, and that's kind of useful, i have never used it but i have heard that you can generate apps with phonegap, so i think your answer is a good contribution... thanks!