# Does the 'extends' option allow me to directly add <li> elements to a custom element, if extending from an <ul> or <ol>?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have a custom element, `<my-element>`. Its purpose is to act just like an `<ol>` element. I'm instantiating it using:

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement { ... }
window.customElements.define('my-element', MyElement, { extends: 'ol' });
```

My generated HTML looks like this:

```html
<my-element>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</my-element>
```

Naturally, this fails basic HTML validation:

> Error: Element li not allowed as child of element my-element in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> Contexts in which element li may be used:
>
> - Inside ol elements.
> - Inside ul elements.

However the validator does not know I'm extending from an `<ol>` element to begin with. Does the presence of `extends: 'ol'` allow me to add `<li>` elements directly into my component, or do I still need to provide an `<ol>` wrapper?

---

Note: This question is very similar to [put a `<custom-tag>` instead of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` to create a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753027/put-a-custom-tag-instead-of-a-ul-or-ol-to-create-a-list), but that fails to mention the `extends` option when defining a new custom element. For this reason I saw fit to create a new question instead of potentially mangling the meaning of that one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec Custom Elements will be able to, eventually, extend other elements. But now is not the time.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements#extend

> Warning: At time of writing, no browser has implemented customized built-in elements ([status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4670146924773376)).

But that does not prevent your custom element from acting like another element.

Just look into all of the required ARIA attributes and what CSS you would need and go for it.

Comment: This is the right answer. Unfortunately Apple is more or less blocking the `[is]` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works with `{extends: 'ol'}`.

But don't forget the Customized Built-in Elements are defined by using the original element tag with the `is` attribute.

```
<ol is="my-element">
    <li>...
    <li>...
</ol>
```

Also, your class must extend `HTMLOListElement`:

```
class MyElement extends HTMLOListElement {...}
```

It works [natively with Chrome version 67](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements%20v1) and above:

```js
customElements.define( 'my-element', class extends HTMLOListElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.addEventListener('click', ev => 
        console.info( 'click on ' + ev.target.textContent) 
    )
  }
}, { extends: 'ol' } )
```

```html
<ol is="my-element">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ol>
```

For the other browsers you can use [a polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element).